# Why doesn't clock.tick() measure time accurately in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've created a simple game in Pygame that displays an image of a certain emotion for x amount of time, before giving participants the opportunity to select which emotion was displayed by pressing a button. However, I'm having trouble maintaining the display time for images. I use clock.tick() to get a value for delta time, but it seems that it's 3x slower than it should be. If I set the timer to 1000ms, for example, the image is displayed for ~3 seconds, whereas I only want it to display for 1 second. I can always divide the display time by 3 to get it roughly correct, but I want to understand what's causing this.
Here's the main game loop:

```
def mainGame(images):
dt = 0    #delta time is set to 0 to begin
timer = displayTime #displayTime by default is 1000ms
imageNumber = 0
gameState = States.VIEWING    #this is the game state where a participant views a question
running = True
while running:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    mainDisplay()             #this displays the answer buttons
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False


    if ( gameState == States.VIEWING):
        dt = clock.tick_busy_loop(30)   #should increase delta time by however many ms have passed
        timer -= dt                     #minus delta time from the timer
        if timer >= 0:                  #if the timer remains above 0, continue displaying image
            askQuestion(images, imageNumber)
        else:                           #when timer reaches 0, stop displaying image and move to answering state
            gameState = States.ANSWERING
            

    elif (gameState == States.ANSWERING):     #this is where participants select their answer
        timer = displayTime                   #reset the timer
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        mainDisplay()                         #displays answer buttons
        for emotion, rects in rectDict.items(): #this detects whether a button has been clicked or not
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if rects.collidepoint(mouse):            #if a button is clicked
                    gameState = States.VIEWING           #switch back to viewing state
                    answers.append(emotion)                 #add answer to answer list
                    imageNumber += 1                    #move to the next image
                elif not any(rect.collidepoint(mouse) for rect in rectList):   #if a button is not clicked
                    print("You did not select an answer")
                    break

    if practice == True:   #if in practice mood, stop when number of practice questions is reached
        if len(answers) == pnumberofQuestions:
            break
    elif practice == False: #if in main game loop, stop when number of questions is reached
        if len(answers) == numberofQuestions:
            break

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new clock each pass through the `while` loop.

Move

```
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

out of your

```
while running:
```

and put it somewhere above it.

Comment: Thank you @Glenn Mackintosh - I moved clock = pygame.time.Clock() above the while running statement. It seems to be working for the first image blit in terms of timing, but then subsequent image blits don't seem to be showing up following that. 
If I print(timer) every frame to try and troubleshoot, the timer reduces as expected from 1000 to 0 for the first blit, but then when I click on an answer the timer value changes to something like -1000, whereas before it would reset back to 1000 every time.

This occurs after I move clock = ... to above the while loop with no other changes.

Comment: Never mind - I think I solved it! The issue was, clock.tick() returns the number of ms since it was last called. Because clock.tick() was only being called during the VIEWING state, when I went to the ANSWERING state and took some time to answer the question, clock.tick() would return the number of ms I took to answer after I moved back to the VIEWING state and clock.tick() was called again. 

To solve it, I moved dt = clock.tick() to underneath "while running:", ensuring that clock.tick() is being called every frame, not just in the viewing state. 

Thanks again for your help!